# rsync re-syncing files each time

Tags: lubuntu, sync, music, rsync

I'm trying to sync the Music folder from my computer with lubuntu 19.10 to my Pixel 2's Music folder via USB. I'm able to mount the device using `jmtpfs` to a Folder called "Celular". Then what I want to do is use rsync.
I do:

`rsync -avn Music/ Celular/...`

And it shows my music, then I do:

`rsync -a Music/ Celular/...`

And it works, the files are on my phone and I can play the music. But then if I do:

`rsync -avn Music/ Celular/...` It again shows me the exact same files as before.

It appears to me that this has something to do with my phone because for other folders it works fine.

What causes this and how can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, `rsync -n` this -n switch is to perform a test and tell you a result and does NOT copy files. I hope you are kidding us and read carefully `man rsync` if you are serious.

Comment: Yes, I know it's a test, but it shouldn't show anything since all the files from the source are already in the destination, however it behaves as if none of the files were in the destination.

Comment: Then another thing in doubt is on the protocol that connects Phone and Computer doesn't do the work and is not really reliable.

Comment: Although Android is based on Linux it doesn't update the files last access date which might break `rsync`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to check what `rsync` is actually doing.

Try this (add the `-n` if you are just testing):

```
$ rsync -avi Music/ Celular/...
```

The `-i` flag will list the actual changes `rsync` is doing ([this might help understand it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493525/what-does-f-mean-in-rsync-logs)). Sometimes, if the time resolution of the other filesystem is no the same, you might end up syncing (trying to sync actually) the timestamps, over and over again. Same thing if the permissions cannot be synced (you can solve things like these with switches, such as `--no-perms` for example).

If the itemized changes do show that the whole file is being transmitted, you might need to change the algorithm used by `rsync` to check if two files are different. See the description of `--checksum` to know more about the default quick check and the checksum alternative.

Comment: you were right, literally all files had a "t" and some had aldo a "p". First I tried with --no-perms and --no-times but then it appeared a "T" that I couldn't fix, at last i used --only-size and it worked. Thank you! I would still like to know if there is a better solution or what causes this.

Comment: If the other filesystem cannot handle the permissions you would have to ignore them, or you could use other flags (`-a` implies `-rlptgoD`, you might need to just use the ones you need instead of using `-a` followed by `--no-...`). For time differences `--modify-window` can also help. The cause: different filesystems might have different notions of permissions, times, links, etc. and that means some filesystem data cannot be synced.

Answer (score 0):

`rsync` can use the `-u` flag to update only those files that have changed in the source. Try running:

`rsync -avun Music/ Celular/...`

And see if it's still trying to copy all files.

Comment: Unfortunately it is still trying to copy the files